# Who was the dead body that the Red Dragon left for the FBI?

Tags: hannibal-tv

In the TV show *Hannibal*, season 3, the FBI found a body, after the blind woman (Reba) escapes from a burning building.

Since this body's head was shot off with a shogun and badly burnt, FBI initially believed this was the Red Dragon himself.

Later it turned out that it was a ruse by the Red Dragon.

In the movie *Red Dragon*, this dead body was a colleague to the Red Dragon and Reba. In the TV show, who was it?

Comment: I see now that it is in the last episode of season 3. If I have time I will rewatch it. I just remember that they quickly deduce that it was not his, but I don't remember if they ever show the assault/murder and/or if the victim's name was named-dropped.